# Is it possible to assign CSS properties on specific zoom?

Tags: css, zooming

In pseudo-code, something like this:

```
div:zoom(2){
    color:red;
}
```

which should set color of all the divs to red when the zoom is 2x.

Is it possible with pure CSS?

Comment: To access information that is either outside the DOM tree or difficult to access in the DOM tree, you go to use pseudo classes and pseudo elements. think of it as a compliment to pure CSS, which cannot be expressed by using normal selector

Comment: What do you mean by `zoom`? Do you mean a user zoom triggered by the OS? By the browser? Or do you mean the actual `zoom` property within CSS?

Comment: Assuming you mean browser zoom, I don't think CSS has browser zoom selector. [Detecting browser zoom is not trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers). You might be better off trying to make your content work at different zoom levels.

Comment: @hello by zoom I mean when user increases the size of the window content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t really detect if a user zooms a page. This is due to these restrictions:

- CSS is not able to get such information except via Media Queries. But even in Media Queries Level 4 (not implemented yet by any browser) there’s no zoom level detection.
- Browser zoom can be two ways: font-size zoom or page zoom.

For the latter, with JavaScript there are some possibilities to detect the zoom level. You better shouldn’t rely on it and I’d consider twice if to include such a hacky script into a codebase.

See this answer on Stack Overlow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078596/3689130
See this Github repository: https://github.com/yonran/detect-zoom

Comment: I ask about page zoom. So not possible? Ok. Thanks for the info!

Comment: As said, it’s somehow possible (as the github repo does) but it’s a hacky solution and I wouldn’t use it for production sites/applications. :)